# how can I create this kind of filter box for a certain field in admin pages? django

Tags: python, django, filter, model, customization

let's say I have an employee model with the field username which can be selected.  Usually in admin > employee page, we will see a dropdown of a list of employee username but instead of doing that, is it possible to have like a select list and on top of that there's a filter so it'll be easier to find what is needed instead of scrolling through the whole dropdown if there are like hundreds....

an example of what I want is like this....
[image]
so in the box it'll be like list of the employee's name so I can click and choose whichever needed and also use filter to find the username.

this image is actually cropped from admin > users

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This is auto generate form input when there is manytoMany relation in your model.

Fox ex, something like this.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    members= models.ManyToManyField(Employee)
```

In  you admin.py you have to register your model to show in admin pages.

```
class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('employees',)


admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

There is more evolved selection also possibly with some customisation.

Comment: is this only for `ManyToManyField`? also, where do I add this in order to add it into the admin pages?

Comment: what if I already have something like `class Team(admin.ModelAdmin)` ? also this doesn't give me that filter thing on top does it? also, so this means it wouldn't work for just foreign keys?

Comment: There could be conflict if you give your AdminName same as you model name. i.e. Team here. And yes AFAIK it is for manytomany field. And not for foreign keys as such.

Comment: In that case what you must be referring to is to have multiple records which is not valid here at all. You can look at admin Inline forms here.